# code for creating plot of seasonal variability with monthly data?

Tags: r, plot, mean

```
Year   Mean    SD
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Jun    277. 230. 
 2 Jul    249. 113. 
 3 Aug    273. 129. 
 4 Sep    278. 124. 
 5 Oct    310. 118. 
 6 Nov    291. 107. 
 7 Dec    352.  90.4
 8 Jan    355. 121. 
 9 Feb    517. 422. 
10 Mar    366. 186. 
11 Apr    355. 315. 
12 May    239. 136.
```

[image]
how to show this plot with these data in R?
any helpful code?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Could yo provide that code?

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(forecast)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo
decomp <- stl(gas, 5)
plot(decomp)
```

[image]

```r
print(head(decomp$time.series))
#>           seasonal    trend  remainder
#> Jan 1956 -330.9170 2015.744  24.173111
#> Feb 1956 -402.1667 2020.906  27.261128
#> Mar 1956 -238.4648 2026.067   6.397573
#> Apr 1956 -151.6784 2031.229  -1.550535
#> May 1956  170.7040 2036.306 -34.010462
#> Jun 1956  275.1713 2041.384   4.444837
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>